# How to save Data and Time from TextView to SQLite?

Tags: android, database, time, android-date

In my app I have 2 buttons which opens a Time Dialog/Date Dialog and then I select the date and time and then press OK. Thefore the value gets shown in a TextView (for each one), so I need to get the VALUE from the TextViews and save it in the database.

**database row** = `date`

Code for Time shown in TextView:

```
tvHora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHora);

    final Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = d.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //set current time into textview
    tvHora.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
```

Code for Date shown in TextView:

```
tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //SET CURRENT DATE INTO TEXTVIEW

    tvData.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-"));
```

Code when I click the SAVE button:

```
                        ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
                        valor.put("mensagenssalvas", resultado);
                        db.insert("mensagens", null, valor);
```

So how do I get the values from the textviews to save in the database?

**EDIT**
TimePicker Dialog:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            //set current time into textview
            tvHora.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));

        }
    };
```

DatePicker Dialog:

```
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            year = Year;
            month = monthOfYear;
            day = dayOfMonth;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvData.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));
        }

    };
```

Comment: In order to help you better it would be beneficial to see the code that creates the dialogs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the value as an number in SQLite to make it compatible since SQLite doesn't have built in date/time data types.

You will want to save the value in the DatePicke's `OnDateSetListener`.

To give you an example on how to do this is exactly depends largely on how you create the date pickers. Assuming the values are set you can use the code below. Note that it assumes tvData and tvHora are in class properties (global variables to the class), this way you can reuse them once you set them (which should be done in onCreate)
Perhaps something like this would work:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//keep your current code for the date/time pickers..

public void saveData(View button) {
    String dateStr = tvData.getText().toString();
    String timeStr = tvHora.getText().toString();

    //only save if both fields are non empty 
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dateStr) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(timeStr)) {
       try {
         Date d = parser.parse(dateStr + " " + timeStr);
         ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
         valor.put("mensagenssalvas", d.getTime());
         db.insert("mensagens", null, valor);
       } catch(ParseException ex) {
          Log.e("YOURTAG", "Error parsing date", ex);
       }
    } else {
      Log.d("YOURTAG", "Both fields not present, can't save");
    }

}
```

In your xml layout for the file make a save button like this:

```
<Button  android:id="@+id/Save"
            android:onClick="saveData"
            android:text="Save" />
```

Or if you don't want to put the onClick in xml,  you can do the same thing in code like this:

```
Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View button) {
        saveData(button);
      }

});
```

Comment: Hmm okay, but why the `d.getTime()` why the `getTime`?if im already setting the data/time value from the Dialogs to the textviews? or im wrong?

Comment: getTime returns a long (long integer) which can be used on the reverse side to format back to a text string the user understands

Comment: so you take date entered (text) convert to date, then take that date, and get the timestamp and store to DB. Then on the flip side you would get the timestamp from db, convert to date, then format for the user. This is better than saving as a String because it uses less space in the DB, it sorts correctly and efficiently, it also is less work to format for different user locales.. Lastly, getTime automatically uses GMT so the date value is more not ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, its giving me errors in this line: `Date d = parser.parse(dateStr);` . if i click to import `java.sql` this error show: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date` // if i click to import `java.util` this error show: `Unhandled exception type ParseException`

Comment: and by the way i do have to use this: tvHora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHora); and the same for the tvData right?So it knows where its pulling the data i guess.

Comment: import java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Comment: still errors here, says: `Unhandled exception type ParseException` than it suggests me to surround with try/catch.

Comment: yeah I'm hoping as an android/java programmer you know about exceptions. sorry I didn't write all the code out, just giving you the ideas.. I updated now though.

Comment: oh, ok now im really confuse. I should just put it in the code or inside something? because it must be inside the SAVE button click in order to save in the database ... AH im really confused right now.

Comment: please look at my answer above. And for future reference please try and follow some tutorials and things on these topics first.

Comment: ok, do I really have to put the onClick in XML or create the method saveData() ? can't i just put the if/else function inside my already Save button?

Comment: and is not only the date/time that needs to be saved in the database, there is some other things aswell so i keep the db.insert inside the if or not?

Comment: Haha, sorry, Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey, when I click the save message button it runs normally but in my LogCat this error appears: `Error parsing date` `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2012-10-16- 19:17`  `at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:645)`

Comment: make sure your format matches the format string I posted. It looks like you have an extra - at the end of the date portion. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

see you can regiseter
    **OnDateSetListener** 
listener on the dialog which will get fired when you press the OK button.
e.g

```
OnDateSetListener
{           
           @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

        // here you can set the date to the textview as you want
     }
}
```

Coming to your second point if you want to store this date into your SQLITE database this date or time will be automatically converted into string. Please read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/datatype3.html) . So put it in any of your format such as 
dd-MM-yyyy and store it. and while retrieving read as a string and convert into date format as you want